# How to connect to SQL Server 2017 on a network computer (That is listening to a local port)

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I would like to connect to a database that runs locally on one of our network computers here at work. I can connect to it just fine with the application that I developed that uses Java's sql driver manager. Now I would like to distribute it to the different computers on the network. To do this, I need a url that will point to the database through the network. The database is listening to port 1434.  (Static URL string is "//localhost:1434")
`MatsysUI.setConnection(DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver:" + MatsysIO.getStaticURL(), txtUser.getText(), txtPassword.getText()));`

Problem is, I don't know where to start to find that, and I would like to avoid using an internet connection to connect to this database. Is there a way to route the connection to the network computer, then to its local port?

Comment: Replace "localhost" with the fully qualified domain name (FQDN) of the computer that the database runs on.  Run "ipconfig /all" from a command prompt and look at the "Host Name" and "Primary Dns Suffix" lines.  If you are unsure of how to do that then your network administrator should be able to help you find it.

Comment: Check Microsoft tutorial here: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-access-server-configuration-option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-access-server-configuration-option)

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible answers to this.

I just want to restate your situation to make sure I understand:

- You have an application, written in Java, which requires access to a SQL Server database.
- You want to distribute multiple copies of that application to different client machines.
- The client machines and the database server are all on a local network.
- SQL Server is listening on port 1434
- You need to construct the JDBC connection string on the client machines to access SQL Server.

You give the current connection string as `//localhost:1434`; in that scheme, `localhost` is the hostname. You can replace this with the [fully qualified domain name](https://serverfault.com/questions/73628/equivalent-of-linux-command-hostname-fqdn-in-windows-xp) of the SQL Server machine (this is almost certainly the simplest option). Using the FQDN allows you to replace the machine, or load balance it, etc. without worrying about the connections - but if the machine name ever changes, all your connections break!

You can also connect by IP address - this allows you to change the machine name, but obviously means the IP address can never change. In most circumstances, that's a bad thing.

Your final option is to [look for alL SQL Servers on your network](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44171/find-all-version-of-sql-server-on-a-network), and show them in a drop down for your user (your code suggests you're using username and password inputs). This means you don't have to distribute a new properties file if you want to change your server details.

Comment: You are correct on all of the details listed. An issue that I run into by running `hostname --fqdn` is the error `sethostname: Use the Network Control Panel Applet to set hostname. hostname -s is not supported.` I looked in the control panel for something like this, but could find nothing. How can I fix this?

Comment: You're copying from the question, not the answer - @squillman's comment has the solution.

Comment: Ah! I see, when I ran that I get `Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : SH1565
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :` but using that hostname doesn't work

Comment: please try the other method in the question to which I linked.